# Get a url SSL certificate in javascript

Tags: javascript, web, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a web extension using javascript and I need to get the SSL certificate of the website my extension is running on.

I first did it using NodeJs module openssl-cert-tools.
It works when I do it in the NodeJs console.
Then I ran the browerify command to include NodeJs modules in the javascript. But it doesn't work in the web browser.

Does someone have the solution ?
Thanks!

Comment: `openssl-cert-tools` lists [Node.js as required](https://github.com/frdmn/openssl-cert-tools#requirements--dependencies), so of course it won't work in the browser.

Comment: I succeded using a Node module in javascript after applying browserify command... Are there other methods / tools to do what I want ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll be able to use openssl-cert-tools, as it requires the node runtime. You might look into using a different tool-set, such as [forge](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge/) which might allow you to do what you're looking to do.